# How to convert an eight hexadecimal bytes (16 digits) into decimal value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hex

We are attempting to import a SAS7BDAT file into a SQL Server database.
The only issue we're running into is that source decimal values are being read as float.

Using a command line tool named dsread, we found an option that:

*Converting the IEEE floating-point numeric values in the SAS7BDAT file to their decimal representation may cause a loss of precision. To get a lossless representation of the data, use the /l flag:*

```
sashelp> dsread /v /l prdsale
ACTUAL,PREDICT,COUNTRY,...
0x0000000000e88c40,0x0000000000908a40,CANADA...
0x0000000000388f40,0x0000000000907240,CANADA...
0x0000000000008340,0x0000000000708a40,CANADA...
0x0000000000108440,0x0000000000a88040,CANADA...
0x0000000000808440,0x0000000000308440,CANADA...
0x0000000000a08d40,0x0000000000607e40,CANADA...
...etc...
```

*The numerics are output as eight hexadecimal bytes (16 digits) giving the internal floating-point representation, which can then be used to reconstruct the exact same value in the receiving software. Use /L to get the bytes in big-endian order*

Running some tests, we can see that the decimal value **-1.457263** is being represented by the value **0xcbbbea01f350f7bf** when we use that /L flag.  What we haven't been able to figure out is, how can we convert that hexadecimal value into a SQL Server decimal value?

We've tried many variants, including:

```
select CONVERT(decimal, convert(varbinary,'0xcbbbea01f350f7bf',1))
```

but that results in:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 17
>    Arithmetic overflow error converting varbinary to data type numeric.

Comment: You will need to "compute" the decimal value from the binary representation provided in your file. To do that, you need to understand the logic of how to read the hex value in your example and then convert it to the appropriate decimal value. If you can't do that on paper, you can't really expect to write code to do it. You need to understand endian-ness for one thing.

Comment: try again - it might be easier to import if you export your numbers by converting them to strings

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Smor.
We've tried importing the data as strings as well.  We're seeing exponential values like 7.771561e-16.  We've been given summary numbers for both numeric values in the file and we haven't been able to match them exactly because the two columns keep getting interpreted as float values from the source.  Apparently, using the /L flag the data output is in big-endian order.  I'll research what that means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `0xcbbbea01f350f7bf = -1.457263`, then it looks like that's a IEEE double-precision floating point number with a big endian byte order.

So reverse the bytes (or get it to export in little endian instead)

```
0xcbbbea01f350f7bf -> 0xbff750f301eabbcb
```

Then convert it to a float.  You can use CLR or there's a TSQL function you can try here: 
[Unpacking a binary string with TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662576/unpacking-a-binary-string-with-tsql)

Then convert it to a decimal.

```
select convert(decimal(36,17), dbo.[fnBinaryFloat2Float]( 0xbff750f301eabbcb ), 3)
```

Which, you can see has preserved a closer approximation to the floating point value

```
-1.45726299999999998
```

> Is there a way to reconstruct the "exact same value" with no differences?

Then leave the data as `float(53)` which is exactly the same data type from the source, and don't convert it to decimal at all.  `decimal` and `float` each store finite subsets of the rational numbers, and many numbers can be exactly represented in either system.  But some float values don't have an exact match in decimal, and vice versa.

Comment: Wow David Browne, thank you!  It sounds like it's possible to get a lossless representation of the data, use the /l flag.  The numerics are output as eight hexadecimal bytes (16 digits) giving the internal floating-point representation, which can then be used to reconstruct the exact same value in the receiving software.  

Is there a way to reconstruct the "exact same value" with no differences?